# Why won't scanf take user input for a structure?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, scanf

I have a code with two functions for a school assignment. We've just learned about structures. Both functions must take a pointer to a structure as a parameter. One function is supposed to take in user input to change the values in the structure, and the other is supposed to print out the contents of the structure. Scanf or gets() will not work for me in my first function. I've consulted the chapter in the book and the class notes with no luck. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Traveller {
   int Ticket_ID;
   char Destination;
   float Price;
   };

void CreateTicket(struct Traveller*);
void PrintTicket(struct Traveller*);

main() {

   struct Traveller * str;

   CreateTicket(str);
   PrintTicket(str);

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;

   }

void CreateTicket(struct Traveller* ptr) {

 printf("Please enter your ticket ID.\n");
 scanf("%d", &ptr->Ticket_ID);
 printf("\n\nPlease enter your destination.\n");
 gets(ptr->Destination);
 printf("\n\nPlease enter the price.\n");
 scanf("%f", &ptr->Price);

 }

void PrintTicket(struct Traveller* ptr) {
 printf("\n\n%s\n", ptr->Ticket_ID);
 printf("%s\n", ptr->Destination);
 printf("%.2s\n", ptr->Price);
 }
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: Just think about what is the variable you have created. It's a pointer to a structure, but where is it really pointing to? Have you created any structure variable at all? Maybe you'are trying to pass something by reference; is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll need a return value for main - `int main ()`.
It will help if you initialize the struct to `NULL` before passing it into the functions.
In `gets()` you need to give the address (`&`) to your struct variable.

Hope that helps! I found some other issues with the code but i think it's better for you to figure them out yourself :)

Comment: you need to allocate memory for destination.

Comment: I've always seen people do that with the return value for main but our professor has never told us to do that.

Comment: Well, you end your main with a `return 0` and that sure is an `int`. Even if your professor don't use it, you should. Every function needs to be told what to return.

Answer (score 0):

You had some issues with `printf`s type you tried to print ,`main` was not declared as it should be, and `gets`.

This is the right code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Traveller {
  int Ticket_ID;
  char Destination;
  float Price;
};

void CreateTicket(struct Traveller*);
void PrintTicket(struct Traveller*);

int main(void) {

   struct Traveller * str;

   CreateTicket(str);
   PrintTicket(str);

   return 0;

 }

void CreateTicket(struct Traveller* ptr) {

 printf("Please enter your ticket ID.\n");
 scanf("%d", &ptr->Ticket_ID);
 printf("\n\nPlease enter your destination.\n");
 scanf("%s",&ptr->Destination);
 printf("\n\nPlease enter the price.\n");
 scanf("%f", &ptr->Price);

 }

void PrintTicket(struct Traveller* ptr) {
  printf("\n\n%d\n", ptr->Ticket_ID);
  printf("%s\n", &ptr->Destination);
  printf("%.2f\n", ptr->Price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for the *Structure pointer **ptr***. And change Destination from `char Destination` to `char* Destination`

Make the following changes :

1. Change in **Traveller** structure

   ```
   struct Traveller {
       int Ticket_ID;
       char* Destination;  // change from char to char*
       float Price;
   };
   ```
2. Changes in **main** function

   ```
   int main(void) {

       // Changes Here   (allocate memory)
       struct Traveller * str = (struct Traveller *)malloc(sizeof(struct Traveller));
       str->Destination = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10); // for 9 char + null

       memset(str->Destination, 0, 10);
       // Changes Over

       CreateTicket(str);
       PrintTicket(str);
       return 0;

   }
   ```
3. Changes in **CreateTicket** function

   ```
   void CreateTicket(struct Traveller* ptr) {
       //Rest of the code
       scanf("%s",ptr->Destination);  // don't use &ptr->Destination
   }
   ```
4. Changes in **PrintTicket** function

   ```
   void PrintTicket(struct Traveller* ptr) {
       printf("\n\n%d\n", ptr->Ticket_ID);  // %s to %d
       printf("%s\n", ptr->Destination);
       printf("%.2f\n", ptr->Price);        // %s to %f
   }
   ```

**==Edit (About memset)==**

`void *memset(void *str, int c, size_t n)` copies the character c (an unsigned char) to the first n characters of the string pointed to by the argument str.

`memset(str->Destination, 0, 10);` will put NULL for 10 positions

```
//Change the following
memset(str->Destination, 0, 10);  //not  memset(str->Destination, 10, 0);
```

Comment: Still freezes up when it gets to PrintTicket. Also, we haven't learned what memset() is.